# Where to find and how to learn math vocabulary in Danish?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, physical-resources, danish, specialist-vocabulary

What are good resources for finding out and learning mathematics vocabulary in Danish? How to learn the words to the level of being able to give lecture courses and supervise bachelor's thesis in the subject? I am reasonably proficient in mathematics.

Mathematics vocabulary, for the purposes of this question, includes:

- Basic arithmetic operators and terms
- Elementary functions (such as polynomials, sine, exponentials, logarithms)
- Single and multiple variable calculus, including series, integrals and derivatives
- Proofs and common vocabulary in them (therefore, if and only if, it follows, thus, induction and different steps in a proof by induction, proof by contradiction)
- Analysis in single and more variables (limits, language used in epsilon-delta proofs, Riemann sums, sup and inf, directional derivative)
- Basic algebra and number theory (group theory, ring theory)
- Probability (random variable, expectation, conditional probabilities, marginal distributions)

Answer (score 1):

I, have thus far, used the following methods:

1. Follow a lecture course in Danish. The subject is partially familiar to me and partially new. The material is written in English but spoken in Danish. I ask my questions in Danish when possible and English otherwise. It is a small class of advanced students proficient in English, so this is not disruptive.
2. Browse and read Danish Wikipedia pages on mathematics.

The end result is that, at this point, I can understand mathematical discussions at least as well as casual discussions about something else. This is not enough for lecturing or research, quite yet, but it is not terribly far - mathematical vocabulary is fairly standard and many terms are shared.

The biggest problem for lecturing is that it requires plenty of attention and improvisation even in one's native language, and so is quite demanding in a language in which one is not fluent.