# Acquiring mathematics vocabulary in Norwegian

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, physical-resources, norwegian, specialist-vocabulary

What are good resources for finding out and learning mathematics vocabulary in Norwegian? How to learn the words to the level of being able to give lecture courses and supervise bachelor's thesis in the subject? I am reasonably proficient in mathematics.

The same question with respect to Danish: [Where to find and how to learn math vocabulary in Danish?](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3355/where-to-find-and-how-to-learn-math-vocabulary-in-danish)

Mathematics vocabulary, for the purposes of this question, includes:

- Basic arithmetic operators and terms
- Elementary functions (such as polynomials, sine, exponentials, logarithms)
- Single and multiple variable calculus, including series, integrals and derivatives
- Proofs and common vocabulary in them (therefore, if and only if, it follows, thus, induction and different steps in a proof by induction, proof by contradiction)
- Analysis in single and more variables (limits, language used in epsilon-delta proofs, Riemann sums, sup and inf, directional derivative)
- Basic algebra and number theory (group theory, ring theory)
- Probability (random variable, expectation, conditional probabilities, marginal distributions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The store norske leksikon has many, mostly fairly short, articles on mathematics: https://snl.no/.taxonomy/39 . They are essentially explanations of the meanings of the words with some historical background. The positive side is that the concepts are explained in text, rather than given mere translations to other languages or only definitions.

Matematisk ordliste: https://matematikkradet.no/ordliste/ is a fairly recent initiative, which contains translations of mathematical words: bokmål - nynorsk - English. It is quite comprehensive.

Another, shorter, ordliste: http://folk.uio.no/klara/ordliste/index.html . No nynorsk, but of manageable size and user interface to simply read through.

Wikipedia has a number of mathematics articles på bokmål https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategori:Matematikk and nynorsk https://nn.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kategori:Matematikk . It has all the usual features and flaws of wikipedia: random coverage and quality, but a fair amount of articles.

Answer (score 3):

Here are several resources for mathematics in Norwegian:

- [Norwegian math vocabulary list](http://folk.uio.no/klara/ordliste/index.html) (the closest to what you want)
- [A short word list but contains example sentences](https://www.norwegianclass101.com/norwegian-vocabulary-lists/must-know-math-words-and-phrases/)
- You can buy professional math vocab guides [here](https://velazquezpress.com/products/language/norwegian)