# How to learn the pronunciation of mathematical formulae in Norwegian?

Tags: speaking, norwegian, specialist-vocabulary

Another question concerns acquiring mathematical vocabulary: [Acquiring mathematics vocabulary in Norwegian](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/acquiring-mathematics-vocabulary-in-norwegian)

However, mathematics also includes plenty of formal expressions, such as f(x, y) = (4^x - y^3)^7, and the way to speak these out loud does not follow from knowing the vocabulary. Each branch of mathematics has its own formulas and expressions - matrices, partial derivatives, iterated integrals, commutative diagrams, and so forth.

What are good resources for Norwegian (bokmål or nynorsk) or systematic ways of finding such resources?

A related question at matheducators.SE: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7978/resources-for-reading-mathematics-out-loud-in-different-languages . A good answer there suggests using videos, but finding videos that contain a particular expression, especially something used in higher mathematics, is not trivial.

Comment: Difficult. Being norwegian, this is something I learned by reading norwegian math books and going to classes and lectures held in norwegian. There is a English-Norwegian dictionary for mathematical terms: https://matematikkradet.no/ordliste/         , but this unfortunately says nothing about the pronounciation of these expressions in compound sentences.